# Capturing in monitor mode reports 0 packet for tshark

Tags: networking, wifi, 802.1, tshark

`MacOS 13.4.1`

I'm trying to capture `802.11` management packets with a real `802.11` headers (not just Ethernet header) with `tshark`. So trying to use

```
% sudo tshark -i wifi0 -I -L                 
Data link types of interface wifi0 when in monitor mode (use option -y to set):
  IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header)
```

Then trying to use as suggested

```
% sudo tshark -i wifi0 -I -y IEEE802_11_RADIO   
Capturing on 'Wi-Fi: wifi0'
 ** (tshark:32984) 20:15:55.258837 [Main MESSAGE] -- Capture started.
 ** (tshark:32984) 20:15:55.259162 [Main MESSAGE] -- File: "/var/tmp/wireshark_Wi-FiN4FL81.pcapng"
^Ctshark: 
0 packets captured
```

So after waiting for a few time and then interrupting with `CTRL+C` I got 0 packets captured, but with a regular capturing from the interface `wifi0` it reports a lot of packets with `Ethernet` headers.

Why can't a monitor mode with `-I` capture any packets? Is there a solution for that?